# How to fit a set of equally spaced parallel lines to a grid of data

Tags: python, numpy, least-squares, data-fitting, scipy-optimize

I would like to fit a set of equally spaced parallel lines to a grid of data using a least squares minimization technique. I am able to fit independent parallel lines to my data. However, as expected, the y-intercepts of the fit results are not equally spaced.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
y1 = np.array([60.8, 60.5, 60.5])
y2 = np.array([377.6, 376.8, 377.7])
y3 = np.array([695.4, 695.8, 695.5])

fit_1 = np.polyfit(x,y1,0)
fit_2 = np.polyfit(x,y2,0)
fit_3 = np.polyfit(x,y3,0)

plt.plot(x,y1,'*',x,y2,'*',x,y3,'*')
for line in fit_1,fit_2,fit_3:
    plt.axhline(line, color='r')
```

Parallel lines fit to horizontal data:

[image: parallel lines fit to horizontal data]

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can constrain the spacing to be equal between each subsequent parallel line?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

If you transform your data as below you can then plot a line to this

```
xNew=[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
y =np.concatenate([y1,y2,y3])
```

This line would be y=mx+c where in this fit the x is the index of the dataset.

So we could say for example y1=m*0 + c, y2 = m*1+c etc

you can use this to adjust y1, y2, y3 then fit lines and plot as you were doing

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
y1 = np.array([60.8, 60.5, 60.5])
y2 = np.array([377.6, 376.8, 377.7])
y3 = np.array([695.4, 695.8, 695.5])

xNew=[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
y =np.concatenate([y1,y2,y3]) 

fit = np.polyfit(xNew,y, 1)
y1New = [fit[0]*0 + fit[1]] *3
y2New = [fit[0]*1 + fit[1]] *3
y3New = [fit[0]*2 + fit[1]] *3

fig = plt.figure(num="LIVE", figsize=(14, 6), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.plot(x,y1,'*',x,y2,'*',x,y3,'*')
for line in y1New,y2New,y3New:
    plt.plot(x, line, color='r')
```

This answer will have the same spacing as the average spacing of your 3 fits but it helps you find the exact lines not just the spacing, use this code to see the difference (I adjusted y3[2] to show it here)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
y1 = np.array([60.8, 60.5, 60.5])
y2 = np.array([377.6, 376.8, 377.7])
y3 = np.array([695.4, 695.8, 800])

xNew=[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
y =np.concatenate([y1,y2,y3]) 

fit = np.polyfit(xNew,y, 1)
y1New = [fit[0]*0 + fit[1]] *3
y2New = [fit[0]*1 + fit[1]] *3
y3New = [fit[0]*2 + fit[1]] *3

fig = plt.figure(num="LIVE", figsize=(14, 6), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.plot(x,y1,'*',x,y2,'*',x,y3,'*')
for line in y1New,y2New,y3New:
    plt.plot(x, line, color='r')


fit_1 = np.polyfit(x,y1,0)
fit_2 = np.polyfit(x,y2,0)
fit_3 = np.polyfit(x,y3,0)

for line in fit_1,fit_2,fit_3:
    plt.axhline(line, color='b')

print(float((fit_3 - fit_1)/2))
print(fit[0])
```

Comment: I get the following error when I run `y = np.concatenate(y1, y2, y3)`: `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

Comment: I've added an argument to that line to see if it works. It's just to put them into a single array anyway, I'm sure you can do that

Comment: the right code to fix that is `y = np.concatenate([y1, y2, y3])`, `fit = np.polyfit(xNew, y)` also gives an error: `TypeError: _polyfit_dispatcher() missing 1 required positional argument: 'deg'`

Comment: Fixed. As you can tell, this was just written from memory to give the ideas

Comment: Hi @Alistair, thank you for your suggestion. I am not too sure what you mean by adjusting y1,y2,y3 then fitting lines again using yNew. Can you please explain, perhaps with a working example? 
If I understand correctly, the slope from np.polyfit(xNew,y,1) is my resulting equal spacing which I am trying to determine. I did not expect this result to be the same as simply averaging the spacing between the separate fit results.

Comment: Hi Matthew, I've been able to produce a working example now. I'm not sure if this is the same as the average spacing between your fits, I'd have to have a think

Comment: Thank you @Alistair! This gives me the result that I need. yNew now allows me to properly visualize everything with confidence.

Comment: Glad to hear it, I've added some info on the difference between my result and the average spacing of your fits, if you are happy please accept as the answer